# Can't figure out the configuration settings for YITH Infinite Scrolling

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

I have spent the last two hours trying to figure out the correct selectors to YITH Infinite Scrolling plugin no avail . site: https://dailyinequality.com/

https://s.w.org/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/screenshot-1.jpg?

It says I need the following:

navigation selector

next selector

item selector

content selector

Can't find the correct values . Do I include spaces?

```
<a class="next page-numbers" href="https://dailyinequality.com/page/2/">»</a>
```

tried all combinations

Comment: did not find any issue at my side

Answer (score 0):

It's jQuery-style (also querySelector-style) selectors. So, to target the class "next", you'll have to prepend a period like `.next`.